# Command Pattern: в чем смысл этого шаблона и что он делает

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, java

Объясните пожалуйста в двух словах в чем смысл этого шаблона и что он делает. Прочитал вики, что-то ни черта не понял. Прочитал вот тут: http://articles.javatalks.ru/articles/3
Вроде немного понял, но смысла в этом шаблоне так и не понял, что он делает. В статье говорится про классы "свет" и "телевизор" (можно включать и выключать) и говорится, что с помощью шаблона не нужно изменять старый класс. Но на самом деле в конце концов отдельно для TV создают методы включения-выключения и все остальное, как и у Light..

Comment: > с помощью шаблона не нужно изменять старый класс

Не нужно менять класс `Switcher`, если он один раз написан под работы с командами. Мы просто создаем команды "включить/выключить холодильник", "включить/выключить радио", а `Switcher` будет с ними работать без изменений.

Comment: Основные фишки этого паттерна:

 - изоляция исполнителя вызова от места вызова
 - "вызов как объект" - вы можете складывать команды в коллекции для хранения истории, "проигрывать" эти коллекции команд, даже заворачивать несколько команд в другую команду (получая макрокоманду)

Пример из жизни: когда вы в Word-е делаете Undo/Redo, это как раз работа с коллекцией таких объектов-команд.

Comment: Все же не понял. Зачем какой-то посредник Switcher. Если можно напрямую с методами разных классов работать

Comment: > Зачем какой-то посредник Switcher

Для соблюдения [принципа единственной обязанности](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Например, кнопка панели инструментов ничего не должна знать ни о документе, ни о файлах. Все,что входит в ее обязанности - ловить клики мышкой и вызывать действие. Причем о действии она знает только то, что у него есть метод `execute()`.

Comment: Вообще, советую полюбопытствовать про принципы [SOLID](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) и [закон Деметры](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B), возможно многие вопросы отпадут.

Comment: я тут тоже слежу за темой (сам шаблоны учу) и считаю что на вопрос было очень хорошо отвечено. спасибо топик стартеру и тем кто отвечал :)